# setdiff(x,y) error: returns x instead of values only in x and not in y

Tags: r

I'm not sure why `intersect()` and `setdiff()` from the [Data Transformation Cheatsheet](https://rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/) is returning errors for me. I looked at other answers and couldn't find the answer. Any help would be really appreciated!

---

## Reproducible Example

I'm using `library(tidyverse)` and `library(plyr)` (which I believe is included in `tidyverse` but in trying to figure out the error, I loaded the package anyway). I'm also using `lubridate` for another part in my code so I added it. In my real data, I have lots of redundant values in each table's "code" column so I added duplicate values and piped `distinct()` to replicate the structure I have below.

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(plyr)
library(lubridate)

# x table
x <- tibble(code = c(1,2,2)) %>% 
  distinct(code)

# y table
y <- tibble(code = c(2,3,3)) %>% 
  distinct(code)
```

`intersect()`: I want to use `intersect()` to produce a table of values in x that are also in y: `2`. I found that `join()` works but if anyone can share why what I have doesn't return `2`, I'd appreciate it.

```
# this produces error message "Length of logical index must be 1 or 2, not 0"
intersect(x, y) 

# but this seems to work and returns a table with `2` which is what I want
intersect_solution <- join(x, y, type = "inner")
```

`setdiff()`: I want to use `setdiff()` to produce a table of values in x that are not in y: `1`. I'm stuck here and am completely lost on why this isn't working.

```
# this produces all of x: `1` and `2`
setdiff(x, y)
```

---

**Question Edits:** I had a typo in my code and fixed it. Further additions below:

- intersect(left.df, right.df) changed to intersect(x, y)
- setdiff(left.df, right.df) changed to setdiff(x,y)
- added `library(lubridate)` to example because I'm using it

Comment: I just edited the typo out. That's what I have. My bad!

Comment: On my PC `intersect(x, y)` and `setdiff(x, y)` work as expected.

Comment: Hmm, do you know if library(lubridate) would cause any issues? That's the only difference on my PC and I'm stumped.

Comment: Yes: *The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’* **intersect, setdiff, union** when you make `library(lubridate)`.

Comment: Thanks @GKi! I fixed my errors by declaring `dplyr::intersect(x, y)` and `dplyr::setdiff(x, y)`

Comment: @GKi, I'll accept the answer if you post as an answer. Accept answer option isn't showing up for me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attache `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
```

it shows

> Attache Paket: ‘lubridate’
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:
>
> ```
> intersect, setdiff, union
> ```
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
>
> ```
> date, intersect, setdiff, union
> ```

To access them still from `dplyr` use `dplyr::intersect`, `dplyr::setdiff` and `dplyr::union`.

Comment: Accepted as answer. Thanks again!